# Can't use openssl extension for SSL/TLS protection

Tags: php, laravel, ssl, homestead

I am running Windows 10 working with Laravel 5.4, homestead 2.0, using VM and Vagrant. Everything works... Except when I am running "laravel new blog" I get:

```
  [Composer\Exception\NoSslException]
  The openssl extension is required for SSL/TLS protection but is not 
  available. If you can not enable the openssl extension,
  you can disable this error, at your own risk, by setting the 'disable-tls' 
  option to true.
```

I know that there are some other questions regarding this but there seem yet not to have emerged a good answer for this. Also, most other questions regarding this is about WAMP... Therefor I think it is relevant to ask agiain when using VM.

I have removed the ; (semicolon) in front of *extension=php_openssl.dll* in my php.ini-development and php.ini-production. The error still remains.

When I check openssl version in comandline I have:
*OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...This was due to something wrong with my PHP-install. What I finally did (which is a kinda bad solution) was to install xampp just to get a correct php version. Then I went to my PATH (winbtn + break(paus) ---> Advanced system settings ---> Environment Variables) and re-routed the php to the xampp php version and VOILA! It works. So either dig in to make a proper PHP install or YOLO like me and add xampp just to get a correct php and then it should work. GL HF!